# Failed to start route [A] because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: [E]

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

Getting this error when loading rest definitions via "xml-rests" to Camel Spring Boot 3.2 with the XML path defined in the property camel.springboot.xml-rests = classpath:folder-camel/folder-rest/*.xml

My rest definition file looks as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rests xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.2.0.xsd
       ">
<rest path="/test">
<get uri="/folderuri">
<to uri="log:test-log-rest" />
</get>
</rest>
</rests>
```

The exception stack trace is

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route2 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: http://0.0.0.0:8080/test/nexus12345?httpMethodRestrict=GET%2COPTIONS
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(AbstractCamelContext.java:3351)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(AbstractCamelContext.java:3325)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(AbstractCamelContext.java:3230)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:2992)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2790)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2643)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2606)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2448)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.start(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the root cause of this issue [CAMEL-14969](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14969), I researched for a way to find a simple workaround and came up with the solution to specify route ID on the rest endpoint by surrounding it with the ROUTE tag as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rests xmlns= . . . >
<rest id="id1" path="/test">
  <get id="id2" uri="/folderuri">
    <route id="id4">
      <to id="id3" uri="log:test-log-rest-route" />
    </route>
  </get>
</rest>
</rests>
```